# Sending HTTP response with raw sockets, client doesn't receive message

Tags: java

I am trying to send this message entity body to the client. But, this message seems to be not transmitted. What possible reason is that results in this situation ? String message

```
String message = "HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found\r\n" +
                  "Server: " + 
                 "Content-type: html" +
                 "error\r\n" +
                 "<HTML>" +
                 "<HEAD><TITLE>404</TITLE></HEAD>" +
                 "<BODY>404 Not Found" +
                 "<br> nothing </BODY></HTML>" ;
```

Then, I have used PrintStream instace to send the message, its argument is `message.getBytes()`

The html message is not seen on the browser.

```
  PrintStream sender = new PrintStream(this.socket.getOutputStream());

  String message = // above lines

  sender.write(message.getBytes())
```

Comment: Post your code in which you're sending the message

Comment: @codeMaker look edit, If you want more, please tell me

Comment: Try to get outputstream from the socket via `getOutputStream()` method, then **write** to this stream and **flush** this stream.

Comment: @RafaelOsipov I am not sure I understand well. Can you explain more ?

Comment: I think the reason is some buffering that does socket upon writing your data to the client. And I advised to obtain stream that is being used by this socket, then write directly to this stream, then invoke flush() method of this stream. To send data to the client.

Comment: @RafaelOsipov I have wrote `sender.flush()` after the `sender.write`. But, still html code is not emitted. Why?

Comment: What is on your client side? Are you using web-browser or your custom client application? If it is a browser, then make sure you set properly all HTTP response headers and so on.

Comment: @RafaelOsipov I am using firefox.

Comment: @RafaelOsipov is above basic html or message is wrong ?

Comment: You need a CRLF (carriage return, line feed) after each header. The header fields should not have the ':' character in them. `Content-type` should be `Content-Type`, and there is no standard header named `error` (unless thats a custom one your sending, remove it).

Comment: Also, `html` is not a valid content type, try `text/html`.

Comment: @Perception I understand, can you give your comment as an answer so that I will find a chance to accept it ?

Comment: @demire, sure, see answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you are sending this data across via a raw socket, you need to fix the following:

- You need a CRLF (carriage return, line feed) after each header.
- The header fields should not have the ':' character in them.
- `Content-type` should be `Content-Type`, and there is no standard header named `error` (unless thats a custom one your sending, remove it).
- `html` is not a valid content type, try `text/html`.